# Непросто / не просто кот, между прочим

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Это, сэр, непросто / не просто кот, между прочим.`

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:  *Это, сэр, **не просто** кот, между прочим.*

В данном случае частица ***НЕ*** относится к словосочетанию ***"просто кот"***, поэтому пишется раздельно. Здесь нет наречия ***непросто*** (= сложно, мудрено).

**НЕПРОСТОЙ**, -ая, -ое; -прост, -а, -о. Лишённый простоты; достаточно сложный. Н. вопрос. Н-ое решение проблемы. Человек он н. <Непросто, **нареч. и в функц. сказ.** Сложно, мудрено. Н. задумано. Сделать это довольно н.

Answer (score 1):

Раздельно:

***Это, сэр, не просто кот, между прочим***.

*Не просто* употреблено в значении *не только*. Об этом в [викисловаре, 4 значение](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE), говорится.

Comment: Скажите, а без подстановки "не только" и без Викисловаря можно как-то объяснить раздельное написание НЕ?

Comment: @Sharon Вы уже это объяснили) А я объяснил то, что знал.

Comment: Я чуть позже объяснила. Хочется, чтобы по правилам все было...